# Good webfont for mathematical symbols

Tags: webfonts, google-webfonts

I'm developing a calculator app in HTML5 that needs to print some math symbols like the square root and pi, but the problem is that these symbols aren't defined in most webfonts, so they will appear in the default font, which looks just horrible in comparison to the rest of the input. Is there any webfont (preferably on Google Fonts), that has good support for mathematical symbols?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's probably a bit too late to answer for OP, but for anyone else who finds this post: OP asked for a Google Font that is good for math, I've just been trying all fonts on Google Fonts with a sample of math symbols as seen below.
I've filtered only those that can also be used in Google Docs, meaning expecially a few very nice Noto fonts are missing from the results. Noto Sans Symbols seems to be a subset of Noto Sans that is included only on Google Docs.

This yields the 8 fonts shown below, of which only **M PLUS** seems to have its own implementation for all my test characters including ∛ and ℂ.

At the time of posting, this can be found [here](https://fonts.google.com/selection?selection.family=Coda|Crimson+Text|Gothic+A1|M+PLUS+1p|M+PLUS+Rounded+1c|Nanum+Gothic|Nanum+Myeongjo|Noto+Sans).

[image: Google Fonts with math symbols, usable in Google Docs]

Comment: I guess this must not have existed in 2019, but there is now [Noto Sans Math](https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Sans+Math) on Google Fonts.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use this js library (font)
https://www.mathjax.org/

You can find samples for use on the page.

Comment: Please write here the solution (examples) instead of including a link that could be broken in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The font stix-two-text is now availible on google fonts [here](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/STIX+Two+Text).  If you look on the google fonts page it looks like it has only a few symbols but if you open up the actual fonts google links it seems to have the full  STIX font in ttf form.